# Automate whether the json file data in server machine is getting updated

Tags: bash

I have some n number of files in a server directory. Is there a way to write a bash script that will automate whether the data is getting updated in json file when i access through the portal and if i make any changes manually then it needs to get updated in json file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manipulate [json](/questions/tagged/json) with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script around.

Comment: but how ? i am accessing from remote machine to server machine

Comment: Need more explanations and examples

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, but the question sucks so i suppose its okay :)